# Duplicate sheets based on values count in dynamic range and rename it with the same range values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I want help for google script in spreadsheets.
I want to duplicate sheet named template, with names in range J1:N1 which is on the same spreadsheet in 'base' sheet. Also in range J1:N1 maybe different count values. is it possible to change number of duplicated sheets by values which in the range. For example if in this range 3 values copy template sheet 3 times...
After this I want to rename this duplicates with values in J1:N1 values, and copy the name of duplicated sheets on B2 cell on every duplicate. After all shi process hide template sheet.

This is link to spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-1mrfPwXGrJp3aVhGBFlalPnJ5r28cW9HuTu2OLmHc/edit?usp=sharing

I used this code, but its create only 1 sheet and with number. I need exactly the name for per sheet which is in the range:

```
function makeCopies() {
//getting active spreadsheet
var activeSreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//getting basic sheet
var basicSheet = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("base");
//getting active spreadsheet
var activeSreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//getting template sheet
var templateSheet = activeSreadsheet2.getSheetByName("template");  
//setting template sheet as active
activeSreadsheet2.setActiveSheet(templateSheet);
//getting values from selected range
var rangeArr = basicSheet.getRange("J1:N1").getValues();
//going through range values
for(i = 0; i < rangeArr.length; i++){
//preparing name for new sheet
var name = (i + 2) + '. ' + rangeArr[i][0];
//making duplicate of base sheet
var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
//setting new name for duplicated sheet
newSheet.setName(name)
}
};
```

I found this code too, but it didnt exactly what i want:

```
function createEmployeeSheets() {
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the range of cells that store employee data.
var employeeDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("group");

var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();

var template = ss.getSheetByName('Template');

for (var i=0; i < employeeObjects.length; i++) {

// Put the sheet you want to create in a variable
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(employeeObjects[i]);

// Check if the sheet you want to create already exists. If so,
// log this and loop back. If not, create the new sheet.
if (sheet) {
   Logger.log("Sheet " + employeeObjects[i] + "already exists");
} else {
   template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);
   }
}
return;
```

This code creates dynamic count of sheets from range and 1 additional which can't rename because in range its empty cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please show us what you have tried already and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I add code which used to my question.